# Query with javascript in LightSwitch HTML client

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, visual-studio-lightswitch

LightSwitch tables in play:

- ProductVariant
- ProductVariantDetail (many to one ProductVariant)

Code:

```
myapp.AddEditProduct.Id_render = function (element, contentItem) {
    var detailArray = new Array();

    //contentItem.screen.getProductVariantDetails().then( function(result) {
    //    for (var i in result.data) {
    //        if (result.data[i].ProductVariant.Id == contentItem.value) {
    //            detailArray.push(result.data[i].InventoryDetail.Title);
    //        }
    //    }
    //    $("<div>" + detailArray.join(" / ") + "</div>").appendTo($(element));
    //});

    var filter = "ProductVariant eq " + contentItem.value;
    myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.ProductVariantDetails.filter(filter).
        execute().then(function (result) {
            for (var i in result.results) {
                detailArray.push(result.results[i].InventoryDetail.Title);
            }

        }).then(function() {
            $("<div>" + detailArray.join(" / ") + "</div>").appendTo($(element));
    });
};
```

The commented out code goes through EVERY ProductVariantDetail and checks if the corresponding ProductVariant matches the custom control. I discovered you can retrieve a query client-side (to save server bandwidth, see uncommented code) but my version never makes it inside filter(filter).execute. I tried "ProductVariant.Id eq" for the filter as well. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this 
var filter = "(ProductVariant.Id eq " + msls._toODataString(contentItem.value,":Int32")+")";